# Substitute Text with RegEX in external file Perl

Tags: regex, perl, file-io

I am trying to have a script that will update a variable in an input file. The RegEx matches but it does not perform the substitution. What am I doing wrong.

```
sub updateInputDeck {
my $powerLevel = shift;
my $file = $outputFiles{input};
open INPUTFILE,"<",$file or die "Cannot open file $file $!\n";
while (<INPUTFILE>) {
    if (s/((?<=\s{3}RP\s{2}=\s{2})\d+)/$powerLevel/) {
        print $_;
        print "Updating Input File for Power Level: $powerLevel";
     }
}
close INPUTFILE;
}
```

***UPDATE***

I am trying to update the file pointed to in the filehandle. Can I only do this via a print statement. If that is the case I just want to reprint that one line. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use perl's [in-place editing](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq5.html#How-can-I-use-Perl%27s--i-option-from-within-a-program%3f):

```
sub updateInputDeck {
    my $powerLevel = shift;
    my $file = $outputFiles{input};

    local @ARGV = ($file);
    local $^I = '.bac';
    while( <> ){
        s/((?<=\s{3}RP\s{2}=\s{2})\d+)/$powerLevel/;
        print;
    }

    #unlink "$file$^I" or die "Can't delete backup";

    return;
}
```

Also note, that your use of a global `$outputFiles{input}` as a parameter to your function is a bad style practice.  Instead pass it as a parameter to your function as well.

Comment: I actually like this answer better than my own. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to do it in 2 passes. First read the whole file into an array, edit it locally and write the whole thing back out, overwriting the original file.

```
open INPUTFILE,"<$file" or die "Cannot open file $file $!\n";
my @lines = <INPUTFILE>; # Read in entire file.
close INPUTFILE;

open INPUTFILE,">$file" or die "Cannot open file $file $!\n";
foreach $line (@lines) {
  $line =~ s/((?<=\s{3}RP\s{2}=\s{2})\d+)/$powerLevel/;
  print INPUTFILE $line;
}
close INPUTFILE;
```

Comment: @sguaria just what the doctor ordered

Comment: @Miller's answer is more memory efficient if you have to deal with very large files. I guess this answer is simpler to understand.